# LocalStorage - No XML/JSON

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

In my app I want to keep track of what the user created, so he doesn't have to do it everytime he closes the app

I have no idea how to do so, except that it might be with XML or JSON.

I have no access to a server, it need to be on the device's memory.

Could someone guide me on what i Need to undersand and what i need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Sencha `localStorage` proxy class http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage

It's wrapper around HTML5 local storage capabilities.